# Hibernate one-to-many bidirectional mapping deleting child

Tags: hibernate

I have a big confusion If I am deleting child record all records are deleted including parent.Can some eone explain me how the below code is working.

```
public class Vendor { 
private int vendorId;
private String vendorName;
private Set children;
}

public class Customer {

private int customerId;
private String customerName;    
private Vendor parentObjets;

}

class Test {
Customer customer=(Customer)session.get(Customer.class,1);
session.delete(customer);
}

Vendor.hbm.xml
 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="str.Vendor" table="vendor"> 
<id name="vendorId" column="vendid"  />
<property name="vendorName" column="vendname" length="10"/> 
<set name="children" cascade="all" inverse="true"> 
<key column="custvendid" />
<one-to-many class="str.Customer" /> 
</set> 
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Customer.hbm.xml
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="str.Customer" table="customer"> 
<id name="customerId" column="custid"  />
<property name="customerName" column="custname" length="10"/>   
<many-to-one name="parentObjets" column="custvendid" cascade="all" not-
null="true"/>
```

Vendor table
    Vendid   vendorname
          1    IFL

```
Customer table
custid custname custvendid
 2     XYZ      1
 3     ABC      1
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to remove the `cascade="all"` in the `Customer.hbm.xml`.

If you set `cascade="all"`, then when you perform the remove operation, it is propagated to the parent object.

Please, see the [Hibernate Transitive Persistence documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-transitive) for further details.

Comment: Hi Danilo, I have two questions. First question is. If I am deleting using child all the records are deleted including parent. Second question is. If I change cascade="none" in vendor.hbm.xml and try to delete the child. I am getting the error and I have updated the code for deleting just now.

Comment: Records are deleted since you have `cascade="all"` on both sides of the association: when you delete a child, the parent is deleted as well, and, as a result of the cascade on the parent side, each child is deleted as well. You  have to set `cascade="none"` in the Customer.hbm.xml file, not in the Vendor one.

Comment: If iIchange cascade=none in vendor.hbm.xml file is also working when we have a single record in both vendor table and customer table.I mean customer table should not contain more than one record. This is for deleting using child. But how it is working here.

Comment: And also please provide me some links or references docs how to work with bidirectional relational ships

Comment: Can anyone answer to my question.

Comment: You should better explain what you want to do. Your questions are confusing. Moreover, I suggest you to use a more recent Hibernate version and annotate your model classes instead of using xml files, unless you do not have specific requirements and unmodifiable model. For what concerns relationships mapping, see [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations)

Comment: In bidirectional relational ship what are the operations performed on child side it should reflect on parent side vice-versa. If I am going to delete  customer, for that we have cascade=all in customer.hbm.xml file. Why hibernate is considering cascade=all value of vendor.hbm.xml file. This one I am not getting.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand your english. Please use better grammar, otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: Sorry, I will put it in simple form. In bidirectional relation if we are inserting parent through child. Both parent and child records are inserting into data base.
Records are deleted since you have cascade="all" on both sides of the association: when you delete a child, the parent is deleted as well, and, as a result of the cascade on the parent side, each child is deleted as well. ---By you
Why hibernate is considering cascade on the parent side also ? If I am inserting or deleting using child?.

Comment: Records are deleted since you have cascade="all" on both sides of the association: when you delete a child, the parent is deleted as well, and, as a result of the cascade on the parent side, each child is deleted as well. ---By you.  Why hibernate is considering cascade on the parent side also ? If I am inserting or deleting using child?

Comment: Hibernate is considering cascade on the parent side because you set ´cascade="all"´!!. Please update your question with a clear scenario and explain your problem correctly because, as it is currently written, it is hard to help you. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why hibernate is checking cascade=all at parent side even though we have a cascade=all at child side, if am deleting using child object. As per my understanding what are the operations perform on child side it should reflect at parent side in bidirectional.